# How to bind all the rows of  Dataset in gridview

Tags: asp.net

can you please tell me how to bind dataset to gridview

```
string indno = dsRasisePo.Tables[0].Rows[0]["indno"].ToString();
 for (int i = 0; i < arry.Count; i++)
        {
            string prodid = arry[i].ToString();
            string tid = RaisePurOrder.GetTid(indno, prodid);
            Dataset dsQuotation=RaisePurOrder.Bindquotation(tid);
         }
 gvSelectQuotation.DataSource = dsQuotation;
 gvSelectQuotation.DataBind();
```

indent no is common only so that i gave like that i want to loop it throug the array count and passing the functions i may get more than one row in dataset now what is the problem is only last row of dataset is bindning in gridview but remaining rows are not yet bind

---

Comment: Which Dataset is used by you ? you have dsQuotation, dsquo, dsRasisePo..

Answer (score 3):

Well, This will give an overview how to bind the data with dataset to grid view....

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

   if (!Page.IsPostBack)
   {

          string connectionString = “server=SYS2;” + “integrated security=SSPI;” +  
        “database=ERPFinAccounting”;
     SqlConnection myConnection;
     string str_Account_Select = “SELECT * FROM AccountsTable”;
     SqlCommand myCommand;
     DataSet myDataSet;
     myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
     myConnection.Open();
     myCommand = new SqlCommand(str_Account_Select, myConnection);
     SqlDataAdapter mySQLDataAdapter;
     myDataSet = new DataSet();
     mySQLDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(myCommand);
     mySQLDataAdapter.Fill(myDataSet, “AccountsTable”);
     GridView1.DataSource = myDataSet;
     GridView1.DataBind();

    }
}
```

i hope it will helps you